# fakename() not populating into gmail

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

`fake.name()` appears to give a random name, no errors, but I can see in selenium chromedriver that nothing is input.  Any idea why this is ?

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker('it_IT')
for _ in range(1):
    print(fake.name())



    username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#emailPass")
    username.send_keys(fake.name())
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Any other error message?

Comment: Try `driver.send_keys_to_element(username, fake.name())`

Comment: @RatmirAsanov Unfortunately not.  I'll try Jaxi solution to see if that helps.

Comment: @Jaxi That tends to give me: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys_to_element' .

Comment: Hmm, I was following the webdriver api here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Comment: Are you importing selenium web driver too?

Comment: @Jaxi I thought I was as its inputting the password.  Hmmm

Comment: @Jaxi Perhaps Selenium does not like the syntax fake.name() but rather full words?  Haha, or maybe the solution is blindingly obvious that I've missed it.

Comment: You can always store the fake.name() in a variable and see if that works

Comment: @Jaxi Can you show a quick example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for storing the name as a variable rather than using the function.

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker('it_IT')
for _ in range(1):
    name = fake.name()
    print(name)
    username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#emailPass")
    username.send_keys(name)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  As it turns out the css selector worked but it was a case of working css selector in chrome inspect, but not working in Python Selenium. No error message which is odd, I'll be sure to keep this in mind in the future! :)

Comment: Do you have it fixed in that case?

Comment: Sure do :D. Thanks.  I used an xpath instead.  Did the trick.

Comment: fake.name() creates a new fake name each time.  The above method allows you to get the same fake name.  Very useful.